# How to group sublist to a specific list from database record codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know it's possible to group a sublist to a specific list in php using the records in the database but I have a hard time getting it. For instance I have a list types like **Bags** and **Shoes** . Now I wanted to display a list of items according to their types which is the Bags and Shoes. The items will be listed as a sublist of Bags and Shoes. Now problem is I only got it all looping around using foreach function in php.

Example output to achieve:

Bags

- Backpack
- Bucket bag
- Duffel Bag

Shoes

- Sandals
- Boots
- Flats

Controller:

```
$data['items'] = $this->item_model->get_items('items');
$this->load->view('items', $data);
```

Model:

```
public function get_items () {
  $output = $this->db->get('items');
  return $output->result();
 }
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item):?>
  <li class="list-group-item view" draggble="true">
    <span class="handle">::</span> <?php echo $item->type; ?> //Bags or Shoes
  </li>
   <ul class="list-group list-group-sortable">
    <li class="list-group-item view"><span class="handle">::</span>
     <span class="badge badge-complete">Complete</span>
     <a href="#"><?php echo $item->item_title; ?></a> //Item title
    </li>
   </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `arrays`, arrange your output accordingly in an associative array and then call it in any order you desire , I think the following might help you achieve the desired result -

```
$list = [];

function get_sublist($title){
  return '<ul class="list-group list-group-sortable">
        <li class="list-group-item view"><span class="handle">::</span>
         <span class="badge badge-complete">Complete</span>
         <a href="#">'.$title.'</a>
        </li>
       </ul>';
}

 foreach ($items as $item){
    switch(strtolower($item->type)){
      case "bags":
        $list['bags']['title'] = 
         '<li class="list-group-item view" draggble="true">
            <span class="handle">::</span>'.$item->type.'</li>';
        @$list['bags']['sublist'] .= get_sublist($item->item_title);
      break;
      case "shoes":
        $list['shoes']['title'] = 
         '<li class="list-group-item view" draggble="true">
           <span class="handle">::</span>'.$item->type.'</li>';
        @$list['shoes']['sublist'] .= get_sublist($item->item_title);
      break;
      //add any more types
    }

 }

 echo $list['bags']['title'];
  echo $list['bags']['sublist'];
  echo "<br />";
   echo $list['shoes']['title'];
  echo $list['shoes']['sublist'];
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I prefer to see answers based on CI structure.